# Hide Toolbar on scroll wont work properly [CoordinatorLayout]

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a viewpager with 3 fragments which are using recyclerviews. I am trying to hide the toolbar when the user scrolls the recycled view. My problem is that the toolbar hides/shows when the user scrolls but it does not hide fully. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. To illustrate what exactly is happening I am including two pictures with the two states of the toolbar (hidden and shown).

NOTE: one thing that I noticed when the toolbar is hiding. It does not go "under" the system status bar like it should but goes above it.

shown:
[image]

hidden:
[image]

As it can be seen, the toolbar is not fully hidden. I can see parts of the Toolbar title and overflow icon at the right.

This is my main_layout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.studentsins.lust.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/NavigationTab"/>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/dirtyWhite"
    fab:fab_addButtonSize = "normal"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/createPlanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
        fab:fab_title="Create a plan"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_event_white_48dp"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"/>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/changeStatusBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blood_orange"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_textsms_white_48dp"
        fab:fab_title="Change status"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/dirtyWhite"/>

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The overlap could be occurring because the height of your tab layout is greater than the height of your toolbar.

Comment: Hmm, how I can change it?

Comment: Try setting the tabLayout height to android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: @davehenry I reverted the bellow applied changes and tried your suggestion and it worked! Thanks a lot! Could you, please, add your comment as an answer so I can accept it, because your suggestion actually fixed the original problem. I only found a worked arround.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlap is occurring because your tabLayout height is greater than your toolbar height. You can fix it by setting the tabLayout height to:
 `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 3):

Found a workarround to the problem. in v21/Styles.xml

I had to change the "android:statusBarColor" from "transperant" to any color.

```
<resources>>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/tab_bg</item>
</style>
```